Does concave mean inequality imply majorization?
Let $\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}\in \mathbb{R}^m_{++}$ be such that $\sum_{j=1}^{n}x_{j} = \sum_{j=1}^{n}y_{j}$. Is
$$ \sum_{j=1}^{n}x_{j}^{\rho}\geq\sum_{j=1}^{n}y_{j}^{\rho},\forall\rho\leq1 $$
sufficient to conclude that $\mathbf{x}$ is majorized by $\mathbf{y}$?
I think so but I don't know how to prove it.

What is $\mathbb R_{++}^m$?

Sorry, it should be $\mathbb{R}_{++}^n$. So n-dimensional vectors of strictly positive real numbers.

What means here majorized ? Because if it is coef by coef, you can have $\sum x_i = \sum y_i$ only if $x=y$.

The claim is false as the following counterexample shows: define
$$
x:=\begin{pmatrix}
0.5\\0.3\\0.2
\end{pmatrix}\qquad
y:=\begin{pmatrix}
0.45\\0.45\\0.1
\end{pmatrix};
$$
obviously $\sum_{j=1}^3x_j=1=\sum_{j=1}^3y_j$.
One way to verify that, indeed, $0.5^t+0.3^t+0.2^t\geq 0.45^t+0.45^t+0.1^t$ for all $t\in[0,1]$ is to plot their difference and see that $0.5^t+0.3^t+0.2^t-(0.45^t+0.45^t+0.1^t)$ is a non-negative function on $[0,1]$.

However, $x$ is not majorized by $y$ because $x_1^\downarrow =0.5>0.45=y_1^\downarrow$
